# buffer overrun happens in SystemTimeToVariantTime

Tags: c++, buffer, buffer-overrun

```
void ConvertDateIntoSystemFormat(std::wstring dateModified,DATE& date)
{
SYSTEMTIME systemTime;

memset(&systemTime, 0, sizeof(systemTime));

sscanf_s(ConvertWstringToCharStar(dateModified), "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%dZ",
    &systemTime.wYear, &systemTime.wMonth, &systemTime.wDay, &systemTime.wHour, &systemTime.wMinute, &systemTime.wSecond, &systemTime.wMilliseconds);

SystemTimeToVariantTime(&systemTime, &date);
}
```

Here is my code. It will convert a wstring which contains date and time into`DATE` type.
However, when I run this part of code, it always throw exceptions says "buffer overrun" when the debugger is leaving this function scope.
I alsy tried to chnage it to `void ConvertDateIntoSystemFormat(std::wstring dateModified,DATE* date)` and try to allocate memeory for date when pass it to this function or tried use `LPSYSTEMTIME` instead of `SYSTEMTIME`, or tried `DATE ConvertDateIntoSystemFormat(std::wstring dateModified)` with declare `DATE date` inside the function but none of them works, the buffer overrun problem still happens.
How to fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `SYSTEMTIME` fields have `WORD` type (aka `short`) while format `%d` expects a pointer to an `int`. Fix format string by using `%hd`.